# Pagination Issue in Meteor?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, pagination, meteor

I did  a sample example with to show a person information using collections in meteor.Here i need pagination when showing more persons information.I am also did pagination with the help of bootstrap but not working.So Please see the below code and suggest me what to do?

Code :

```
<template name="userlist">
   <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/bootstrap-paginator.min.js"></script>

   <div class="clist">
       <div class="clistname" style="float:left;width:400px;"><h2>Client List</h2></div>
       <div class="search" style="float:left;width:400px;padding-top:20px;"><div style="float:left;">Serch:</div><div style="float:left;"><input type="text" id="search" /></div></div>
       <div class="addnewuser" style="float:right;padding-top:20px;"><input type="button" id="addnewuserD"  value="Add" /></div>
   </div>

    <div class="chmenu" style="float:left;">
      <table class="cinfotable">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th><div class="cmenu"><u>UserId</u></div></th>

                        <th><div class="cmenu"><u>Patient</u></div></th>

                        <th><div class="cmenu"><u>Address</u></div></th>

                        <th><div class="cmenu"><u>SSN</u></div></th>

                        <th><div class="cmenu"><u>Action</u></div></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody id="udatacontent">

                    {{#each patientInfo}}
                       <tr class="cdata">

                           <td><div class="cname">{{UserId}}</div></td>
                           <td><div class="cdata">
                               <div class="user {{selected}}">{{Firstname}} {{Lastname}}</div>

                                                <div class="userinfo">{{#if selected}}
                                                      City: {{City}}<br>
                                                      State: {{State}}<br>
                                                      Country: {{Country}}<br>
                                                      ZipCode: {{ZipCode}}<br>
                                                      PhoneNo: {{PhoneNo}}<br>
                                                {{/if}}</div>
                               </div></td>
                           <td><div class="cdata">{{City}}<br>
                                                  <br></div></td>
                           <td><div class="cdata">{{SSN}}</div></td>
                           <td><div class="paction">Access Ptient</div></td>

                       </tr>
                    {{/each}}

                </tbody>

            </table>
    </div>


    <script type='text/javascript'>
        var options = {
            currentPage: 3,
            totalPages: 10
        }

        $('#udatacontent').bootstrapPaginator(options);
    </script>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1):

Pagination in meteor works most easily using a table/datagrid package like [reactive-table](https://atmosphere.meteor.com/package/reactive-table). Check the project's GitHub, there are several examples there.

A more powerful pagination package, but not a table enhancement one, is [meteor-pages](https://github.com/alethes/meteor-pages).